# Fill angle text in TikZ

Tags: tikz-angles

I have an angle on a nonuniform background (here simplified as a blue background) making it difficult to read the text of the angle.
I would like to give the text of the angle a half transparent white background to improve readability.

(I'm afraid filling the angle itself is not an option in my application.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (P) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (90+45:1);
\coordinate (P') at ([yshift=1cm] P);

\fill[blue] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,2);

\draw (P) -- (P') (P) -- (A);

\pic[draw, pic text=$\beta$, angle eccentricity = 1.4] {angle = P'--P--A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If it was a normal label I could achieve it like that:

```
label={[fill=white, fill opacity=.5, text opacity=1] $\beta$}
```

but unfortunately that syntax does not seem to work with `pic text`.

Comment: Try `pic text options={fill=white,fill opacity=.5,inner sep=1pt}`

Comment: @esdd yes, that is what I was looking for. thanks a lot. If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pic text options`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (P) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (90+45:1);
\coordinate (P') at ([yshift=1cm] P);

\fill[blue] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,2);

\draw (P) -- (P') (P) -- (A);

\pic[draw,
  pic text=$\beta$,
  pic text options={fill=white,fill opacity=.5,text opacity=1,inner sep=1pt},% <- added
  angle eccentricity = 1.4] {angle = P'--P--A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I would recommend to set `text opacity=1` because by default it will use the value of `fill opacity` which is not what I would want here.